# How to import and use new modules in ocaml?

Tags: string, import, module, ocaml

I am unable to use module Extstring.

Comment: Have you imported the module ?

Comment: Hey I am new to ocaml. So how to do that?

Comment: Check for "import" in Ocaml documentation or books or whatever you are using for reference for the language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running the toplevel, you need to have `exstring.cmo` in its path (the simple way is to run `ocaml` in the same directory as `extstring.cmo`). Then, you can do:

```
# #load "extstring.cmo";;
# Extstring.split "a.b" '.' 2;;
[..]
```

Comment: I got it while running on top level..how to fix that?